# Unable to load release DLL specified in AppInit_DLLs on Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, winapi, development-environment

We hook a library (say xyz.dll) through HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLS path.

I need to debug this library so I created nondebug dll(&pdb) and replaced it with original xyz.dll library in System32 directory. Now when a process tries to load this libary, I get an "bad image" error as following -

"C:\Windows\system32\xyz.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vender for support."

I noticed that original xyz.dll is code signed so I also signed my compiled nondebug xyz.dll with a temporary certificate using signtool, but it didn't help. As per the [MSDN] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463040.aspx) code-sign is recommended but not mandatory.

Later I realized that when I got my nondebug library xyz.dll signed by a valid certificate, it worked.

My question : is there any way so that Windows 7 can bypass the dll's signature verification ? Getting a valid certificate and signing a library every time it is generated seems very cumbersome for development/debugging purpose.  Is there any easy way out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason windows was verifying the digital signature is that xyz.dll was compiled with /integritycheck linker option ON. When I built dll after removing this flag, applications load it without verifying for digital signature.

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195769.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To disable code-signing enforcement for AppInit_DLLs use the following key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs"=dword:00000000
```